# PackageSignatures from adb shell dumpsys

Tags: android, security, adb

I would like to know what exactly means the hashes from the field PackageSignatures when you obtain it with

```
adb shell dumpsys package com.myapp
```

for a given installed app.

I see two hashes:

```
signatures=PackageSignatures{abcabca [xyzxyzxy]}
```

The first one (abc) is different in each installation.
The second one (xyz) is fixed for a given apk.

Moreover, I would like to know whether the second one has any relationship with the public signature of the APK. I have several apks with the same public signature, but the second hash is different. Is that normal?

Comment: Can you give some real-world examples with the `signatures` line from dumpsys plus the output of `apksigner verify --verbose --print-certs <apkfile.apk>` (apksigner is part of the Android SDK).

Answer (score 1):

The signatures line on a recent Android version looks as follows:

```
signatures=PackageSignatures{9122424 version:2, signatures:[bbb2e2d2], past signatures:[]}
```

To understand this line we just have to look into the AOSP source code: [PackageSignatures.java](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageSignatures.java#L311)

## First part

The first part `abcabca` comes from `System.identityHashCode(this)`. Hence it generated the Java hashcode fro the current `PackageSignatures` instance. As this class has only one filed `PackageParser.SigningDetails mSigningDetails;` the hash code totally depends on the fields of the class [SigningDetails](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageParser.java#L5971):

- Signature[] signatures;
- int signatureSchemeVersion;
- ArraySet publicKeys;

## Version part (newer Android versions)

Your used Android version seems to be a bit old, as nowadays the second part is the `signatureSchemeVersion` - at the moment there are three signature schemes known: V1 (jarsigner), v2 and v3.

## Third part (signatures)

The signatures you are interested in is generated by the following code:

```
Integer.toHexString(mSigningDetails.signatures[i].hashCode())
```

Where `signatures[i]` is an instance of the class [`android.content.pm.Signature`](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/pm/Signature.java
).

The `hashCode()` is defined in this class to be generated by `Arrays.hashCode(mSignature);` where `mSignature` is a byte array that seem to contain the encoded version of the used X.509 signature certificate. Alternatively the raw `byte[]` can be supplied, hence it is difficult to tell the concrete content.

But from my understanding on your device this part should be directly linked to the signature of the APK file.